# How do I attach readonly-methods to objects from redux?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

Say I am storing a "user" object with a first name and last name field in redux ( `interface User { firstName : string, lastName : string}` if we are using typescript). Once I retrieve a user from redux, say I want to get the full name of the user, calculated as `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`. Right now, I have a function:

```
function getFullName(user: User) : string { 
  return `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`
}
```

However, in my actual app I have a lot of such read-only functions like this, and would really rather have a method that I can call as `user.getFullName()` or even `user.fullName`. This way, I wouldn't have to remember to import every function, I wouldn't have to remember which things are properties and which are functions, etc.

I suppose I can do this by instantiating classed objects whenever I get anything from redux, and remembering to do `{...user}` when saving to redux to convert to a plain-old-js-object. That would, however, add even more boilerplate to redux, especially with typescript.

This seems like it should be a solved problem, is there an easy, streamlined solution?

Comment: Use a class and store the class instances in Redux? Alternatively, you have a public API that utilises classes and (de)serialize to plain old objects when interacting with the redux store

Answer (score 0):

Member functions in JS objects treated the same as other properties. So you can define member function `getFullName()` on `User` interface and define it in `initalUserState`. `getFullName()` will stay after redux process action.

```
interface User {
    firstName: string; lastName: string;
    getFullName: () => string;
}

const initalUserState: User = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    getFullName () {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    },
}

const reducer: Reducer<User, Action> = (state = initalUserState, action): User => {
    // action processing logic
    return state;
}
```

Spread syntax `{ ...state, firstName: action.firstName }` will still work and will not overwrite `getFullName()` method.

In component you can use `getFullName()`  like below

```
const Cmp1: FC<User> = (user) => <div>{user.getFullName()}</div>

export default connect<User, {}, {}, ApplicationState>
    (state => state.user, null)(Cmp1)
```